# Could Caesar Clown have controlled Smoker?

Tags: one-piece

Smoker is a smoke man. He can "create, control, and transform into smoke at will" – [One Piece wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Moku_Moku_no_Mi)

Caesar is a gas man. He can "create, manipulate, and transform into gas at will." – [One Piece wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gasu_Gasu_no_Mi)

Since smoke is a gas, could Caesar control Smoker when he turns into smoke?

Comment: This is a great question, IMHO. It turns out though, that you more or less answered your own question! For that reason, I added a little extra in my answer, which also attempts to answer how Smoker could possibly fight against Caesar, if they faced off.

Comment: I think Caesar should be able to manipulate water or even blood before doing that, considering that Smoker becomes "smoke" after changing his body state to pure steam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The powers of Gasu Gasu no Mi would certainly allow Caesar Clown to control Smoker when he transforms into smoke using Moku Moku no Mi's powers, provided the smoke is within Caesar's range.

However, Smoker would not be totally helpless if they fought one-on-one since he can fight without using his Moku Moku no Mi powers at all. He can use Haki, and carries the Kairoseki Jitte, both of which would be effective against Caesar.

Comment: As White Dragon answers, "Smoke is not just a gas.", so CC cannot control Smoker.

Answer (score 2):

Smoke is **not** just a gas.

What is smoke?

> Smoke is a collection of airborne solid and liquid particulates and
>   gases... - wikipedia

Before this question can be answered we need to know more about both devil fruit abilities. Like what kind of gas(es) can Caesar (originally) transform into.

> As stated by Caesar himself, he altered his own Devil Fruit with his
>   chemical expertise, adding many of its offensive abilities, thus, the
>   original abilities of the Gasu Gasu no Mi remain uncertain -One Piece Wikia

Unfortunately we don't know enough for example about the types of smoke and gases they can use to really answer the question.

They both can also make there element have a high density to do things like grabbing objects.